# Rails 4 has_one self reference column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, self-reference

I have a Totem model and Totems table.

There will be many totems and I need to store the order of the totems in the database table.
I added a previous_totem_id and next_totem_id to the Totems table to store the order information. I did it via this 
Rails Migration:

```
class AddPreviousNextTotemColumnsToTotems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :totems, :previous_totem_id, :integer
    add_column :totems, :next_totem_id, :integer
  end
end
```

Now in the Model I have defined the relationships:

```
class Totem < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, :presence => true

  has_one :previous_totem, :class_name => 'Totem'
  has_one :next_totem, :class_name => 'Totem'
end
```

I created a couple of these totems through ActiveRecord and tried to use the previous_totem_id column like so:

```
totem = Totem.create! name: 'a1'
Totem.create! name: '1a'
totem.previous_totem_id = Totem.find_by(name: '1a').id
puts totem.previous_totem #This is NIL
```

However, the previous_totem comes back as nil, and I do not see a select statement in the mysql log when calling this line

```
totem.previous_totem
```

Is this relationship recommended? What is the best way to implement a self referencing column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing direction of the association from `has_one` to `belongs_to` and specifying foreign keys, should make your code work as you expected:

```
class Totem < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, :presence => true

  belongs_to :previous_totem, :class_name => 'Totem', foreign_key: :previous_totem_id
  belongs_to :next_totem, :class_name => 'Totem', foreign_key: :next_totem_id
end
```

However, good association should be properly named and declared on both sides - with matching `has_one` association; in this case it's impossible without naming conflicts :) [Self join](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/association_basics.html#self-joins) might be sometimes useful, but i'm not sure if it's the best solution here. I didn't use the gem moveson recommends, but an integer column to store position is something I use and IMHO makes reordering records easier :)

Answer (score 0):

If the only reason for the self-reference is to store the order of the totems, please don't do it this way. It's your lucky day: This is a solved problem!

Use a `position` field and the [acts_as_list](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list) gem, which will take care of this problem for you in a neat and performant way.